# javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"", local:"ProcessCreditApplication"). Expected elements are

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

Here is the java jaxb unmarshal code:

```
    private void fillProcessCreditApplication() {
    try {
        JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(ProcessCreditApplication.class);
        Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
        ProcessCreditApplication processCreditApplication = (ProcessCreditApplication) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(xml);
    } catch (JAXBException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Here is the exception:

> javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"", local:"ProcessCreditApplication"). Expected elements are <{http://www.starstandards.org/STAR}processCreditApplication>,<{http://www.starstandards.org/STAR}processCreditApplicationDataArea>

What does that mean?
Here is the xjc generated ProcessCreditApplication java code:

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "ProcessCreditApplication", propOrder = {
    "applicationArea",
    "dataArea"
})
public class ProcessCreditApplication {

    @XmlElement(name = "ApplicationArea", required = true)
    protected ApplicationArea applicationArea;
    @XmlElement(name = "DataArea", required = true)
    protected ProcessCreditApplicationDataArea dataArea;
...
```

ApplicationArea.java and ProcessCreditApplicationData.java are located in the same folder as ProcessCreditApplication.java.

Here is the incoming xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ProcessCreditApplication xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <ApplicationArea>
    <Sender>
...
```

EDIT: Here is the package-info.java code:

```
@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema(namespace = "http://www.starstandards.org/STAR", elementFormDefault = javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED)
    package org.starstandards.star;
```

EDIT: Here is the code for the generated ProcessCreditApplicationDataArea class:

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "ProcessCreditApplicationDataArea", propOrder = {
    "process",
    "creditApplication"
})
public class ProcessCreditApplicationDataArea {
```

Suggestions?